# How to define horizontal padding of a TextView with android < 8

Tags: android, textview

I am working on a small application for android 6+ with a chat interface using material design. I'm using a text view in order to represent the text but I need to set the padding in order to get something not too ugly.

[image]

But the problem is that I can't use android:paddingHorizontal with android <8, do you know an alternative?

Comment: I did not manage to post my code because he told me that he was not well formatted, here is a hastebin: https://hastebin.com/irixoyiwux.pl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **paddingLeft** and **paddingRight**.

You code will look like this:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/message_body"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name"
            android:background="@drawable/andrew_message"
            android:paddingTop="4pt"
            android:paddingBottom="4pt"
            android:paddingLeft= "14dp"
            android:paddingRight="14dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="@string/fake_text"
            android:textColor="@color/theirMessagesTextColor" android:fontFamily="@font/product_sans_regular"/>
```